# Are there any advantages of connecting to an FTP server using Python compared to Bash/shell?

Tags: python, bash, ftp

I'm currently trying to write a quick script to connect to an FTP server and automatically download a file. While doing some research, I came across [this Superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/98903/how-do-i-check-the-outcome-of-a-ftp-script-with-a-bat-file) and was curious as to whether or not it really is easier to use Python instead of Bash.

I'd like to know of the return code at the end of the connection or file download, and if Python provides better support with that, I'll happily choose Python. Is it possible or difficult to get status codes with Bash or something? Anything else that makes one of the two options difficult?

Comment: I think it's easier, but I'm biased since I know python and not so much bash programming..

Answer (score 2):

When you "use bash" to run an FTP session, you aren't really using bash at all. What you're doing is running a command-line FTP client, and feeding it a list of inputs which mimics what the user would do.

This is usually not a terribly robust method. The interface that's reasonable for a command line connected to a terminal isn't too great for scripting with; for instance, it will use human-readable error messages fed on `stderr` rather than function return calls. The problem is exacerbated by the fact that you usually don't have any decision-making capability in this context, since `bash` is dormant for the period that `ftp` is running. (The exception here is if you were to use `expect` or another similar method. But this is obscure, difficult and far less convenient than a library with an API.)

In Python, by contrast, you're using a library designed for coding with. This is indeed far easier and more robust than trying to ad-hoc script a command-line executable. You have full access to the power of the Python language while running your session; you can react to errors as they occur and implement whatever logic you like to handle failure and success cases. If you're trying to do anything remotely robust or sophisticated, this is preferable.

EDIT: There is an exception to this rule; this is if you are not using an interactive FTP program (such as the default client, `ftp`), but instead a program designed for shell scripting, such as `ncftpget` or `curl`. In this case, you have access to the power of bash scripts for your decision-making, and so the decision is made on the basis of language alone. In general, Python is a better language, runs faster and provides features such as complex data structures and more advanced programming paradigms; bash, meanwhile, is more universally available and can be quicker to write and test. Since the main advantage of bash (assuming the availability of a suitable client program for scripting) is its reduction in the overhead associated with creating the script, it's usually better for very small programs (not more than dozens of lines).